Python Flask SocketIo async
How can I make the socket run asynchronously?
This code doesn't work now. Nothing happens when the socket is called.
I need to call an asynchronous function internally. What should I do?
Here is my code:
socketio = SocketIO(application) 

@socketio.event
def message():
    ....
    ....
    ....
    await onUploadData()


Your code is incomplete.

Flask-SocketIO does not support asynchronous handlers. If you need to write an asynchronous Socket.IO application use python-socketio, which fully supports asyncio.
